# how to find minimum and maximum values inside collections.defaultdict

Tags: python-3.x

good day!

I'm trying to find the minimum and maximum values for a given dataset

```
foo,1,1
foo,2,5
foo,3,0
bar,1,5
bar,2,0
bar,3,0
foo,1,1
foo,2,2
foo,3,4
bar,1,4
bar,2,0
bar,3,1
foo,1,4
foo,2,2
foo,3,3
bar,1,1
bar,2,3
bar,3,0
```

I try to sort my data using the 1st and the 2nd columns as ID and the 3rd column as value

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open("file1.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        meta = line[0]
        id_ = line[1]
        value = line[2]
        try:
            value = int(line[2])
            data[meta+id_].append(value)
        except ValueError:
            print ('nope', sep='')
```

the output of my function is:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'foo1': ['1', '1', '4'],
             'foo2': ['5', '2', '2'],
             'foo3': ['0', '4', '3'],
             'bar1': ['5', '4', '1'],
             'bar2': ['0', '0', '3'],
             'bar3': ['0', '1', '0']})
```

please advice how can I get minimum and maximum values for each ID?

so I need output of something like this:

```
 defaultdict(list,
                {'foo1': ['1', '4'],
                 'foo2': ['2', '5'],
                 'foo3': ['0', '4'],
                 'bar1': ['1', '5'],
                 'bar2': ['0', '3'],
                 'bar3': ['0', '1']})
```

**Update:**

with @AndiFB help I add sorting to my lists:

```
def sorting_func(string):
    return int(string)

from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open("file1.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip().split(',')
        meta = line[0]
        id_ = line[1]
        value = line[2]
        try:
            if value != "-":
                value = int(line[2])
                data[meta+id_].append(value)
                data[meta+id_].sort(key=sorting_func)
                print("max:", *data[meta+id_][-1:], 'min:',*data[meta+id_][:1])
        except ValueError:
            print ('nope', sep='')
                        
data
```

Output:

```
max: 1 min: 1
max: 5 min: 5
max: 0 min: 0
max: 5 min: 5
max: 0 min: 0
max: 0 min: 0
max: 1 min: 1
max: 5 min: 2
max: 4 min: 0
max: 5 min: 4
max: 0 min: 0
max: 1 min: 0
max: 4 min: 1
max: 5 min: 2
max: 4 min: 0
max: 5 min: 1
max: 3 min: 0
max: 1 min: 0
defaultdict(list,
            {'foo1': [1, 1, 4],
             'foo2': [2, 2, 5],
             'foo3': [0, 3, 4],
             'bar1': [1, 4, 5],
             'bar2': [0, 0, 3],
             'bar3': [0, 0, 1]})
```

Please advice how to save only min and max(the first and the last) values in the list?

to get something like this:

```
defaultdict(list,
                {'foo1': ['1', '4'],
                 'foo2': ['2', '5'],
                 'foo3': ['0', '4'],
                 'bar1': ['1', '5'],
                 'bar2': ['0', '3'],
                 'bar3': ['0', '1']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sorting_func(string):
    return int(string)


d = defaultdict(list)
d['python'].append('10')
d['python'].append('2')
d['python'].append('5')

print("d['python'].__contains__('10'): {}".format(d['python'].__contains__('10')))
print(str(d['python']))
d['python'].sort(key=sorting_func)
print('d["python"]: ' + str(d['python']))
print('d["python"][0]: ' + d['python'][0])
print('d["python"][2]: ' + d['python'][2])
print(str(len(d['python'])))
```

Resulting in the following output

```
d['python'].__contains__('10'): True
['10', '2', '5']
d["python"]: ['2', '5', '10']
d["python"][0]: 2
d["python"][2]: 10
3
```

You can sort the List leaving in the first position the minimum value, and in the last one
the max value

Be aware that if the string contained in the dic can not be casted to Int will result in an exception. The sorting function expects a number to compare. For example another sorting function could be:

```
def sorting_func(string):
    return len(string)
```

This one sorts by the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on the dataset an easy way to achieve this would be using pandas and then doing a groupby on `id` and aggregating on `values` to get min and max values for each id

```
#your question

s ="""foo,1,1
foo,2,5
foo,3,0
bar,1,5
bar,2,0
bar,3,0
foo,1,1
foo,2,2
foo,3,4
bar,1,4
bar,2,0
bar,3,1
foo,1,4
foo,2,2
foo,3,3
bar,1,1
bar,2,3
bar,3,0"""

#splitting on new line

t = s.split('\n')

#creating datframe with comma separation
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([i.split(',') for i in t])

Output:

>>> df
      0  1  2
0   foo  1  1
1   foo  2  5
2   foo  3  0
3   bar  1  5
4   bar  2  0
5   bar  3  0
6   foo  1  1
7   foo  2  2
8   foo  3  4
9   bar  1  4
10  bar  2  0
11  bar  3  1
12  foo  1  4
13  foo  2  2
14  foo  3  3
15  bar  1  1
16  bar  2  3
17  bar  3  0

#creating id column by concatenating column 1 and 2, renaming column 2 as 'value' and dropping them col1 and 2
df['id']=df[0]+df[1]
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[2]: 'value'})
df = df.drop([0,1], axis = 1)

Output:

>>> df
   value    id
0      1  foo1
1      5  foo2
2      0  foo3
3      5  bar1
4      0  bar2
5      0  bar3
6      1  foo1
7      2  foo2
8      4  foo3
9      4  bar1
10     0  bar2
11     1  bar3
12     4  foo1
13     2  foo2
14     3  foo3
15     1  bar1
16     3  bar2
17     0  bar3

#doing grouby and aggregating to get min and max for each id

df.groupby('id').value.agg([min,max])

Output:

     min max
id          
bar1   1   5
bar2   0   3
bar3   0   1
foo1   1   4
foo2   2   5
foo3   0   4
```

Comment: thanks but I try to do this tasks without pandas